# C#/SqlServer memory leak

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, linq

I have some problems on my server (Windows Server 2012 r2). Memory is always around 80% of usage and sometimes the CPU too and the hosted apps crash randomly (OutOfMemoryException).

There are about 110 apps on IIS and 95 databases on SQL Server.

The SqlServer machine has ~6500MB of RAM and the IIS machine has ~1400MB of RAM.

There is no reason memory is so high because apps are not constantly requested. I'm wondering if the way I request on sql server is the right way.

This is my function :

```
public static DataSet SQLServerRequest(string SQL, clsDatabase database)
{
    SqlConnection myConnection = null;
    DataSet toReturn = new DataSet();
    try
    {
        using (myConnection = new SqlConnection(database.DBConnectionString))
        {
            myConnection.Open();
            using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(SQL, myConnection))
            {
                da.Fill(toReturn);
            }
        }
        return toReturn;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        log.Error(SQL + " / Exception : " + ex.Message);
        return null;
    } 
}
```

Because I can see on SQL Server :

[image]

Is it a huge problem? Will moving to Adhoc or LinqSql query help memory going down? Am I looking in the right direction?

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/47431/why-is-sql-server-consuming-more-server-memory

Comment: Do you use parameters anywhere at all, or do you construct your queries by concatenating text? The latter is a huge red flag for SQL injection, as well as the production of lots of one-off plans of course.

Comment: can you show me your query ?

Comment: I understand this behaviour is completely normal about the memory, thx you for your feedback. As SQL developer do you think using Ad hoc way instead of brut query like this example ( http://www.beansoftware.com/ASP.NET-Tutorials/Build-Ad-Hoc-Queries.aspx ) is a better solution ?

Comment: linqSQL will not help in your situation, but it can prevent the issue mentioned by @JeroenMostert. you may trace more log (sql monitor, sql log, event viewer) in order to find out what had been done before memory issue (deadlock? auto-retry?attack?) before asserting it is due to machine limitation

Comment: Yes, I construct my queries by concatening text. Is "dangerous" because of lots of one-off plans or just not the right way to do or maybe am I doing well ?

Comment: If you need more guidance on dynamic search conditions (if that's why queries are built up dynamically) see [this](http://sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html) (long read, but worth it). Even when you *need* to build queries dynamically (and you often don't!), using parameters is almost always a good idea. See also the ["optimize for ad-hoc workloads" setting](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/optimize-for-ad-hoc-workloads-server-configuration-option), which is also almost always a good idea (but not better by itself than actually fixing your queries).

Comment: Are any of the C# apps building delimited files with the return data?